# Looking to call a controller function when ng-if="variable" is true

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a html script from where I am trying to call a function present in the controller if ng-if="item.value" returns true. Here is the snippet

```
<td class="rsp-p1">
        <span ng-if="item.result">
          {$ ctrl.hw_interface $}</span>
</td>
```

So here, the flow I am looking is if ng-if returns true call a function driverInfo() and then that function sets the value I want inside hw_interface variable and hence I am displaying that value in above snippet as $strl.hw_interface
But I am unable to find an appropriate method for doing that. I tried ng-init(). Your inputs are much appreciated :)

Here is my angularjs code

```
function driverInfo() {
  ironic.driverInfo(ctrl.driver,'power').then(function(response){
  alert(response)
  ctrl.hw_interface = response;
  });
}
```

(This function signature right now does not have a parameter, once I figure out the way to call i will update the signature.)

Comment: Can you post your AngularJS code?

Comment: Sure updated the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-init` should have worked just fine:

```
<span ng-if="item.result" ng-init="yourFn()"></span>
```

However, do you know what will cause `item.result` to change? Can you react to that change in the controller and call your function there instead?

Comment: Umm, let me see. Actually I can, because "item", I am reading that from different controller method.

Comment: Actually your idea sparked me to check the method that reacts to item.result and basically that is a init() and hence can call the driverInfo() from that itself. Solving the problem. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try some like

```
ctrl.myfunc = function() {
   //do some time consuming work
   return false; //true;
};

<td class="rsp-p1">
   <span ng-if="ctrl.myfunct()">
      {{ ctrl.hw_interface }}
   </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi DelhiPanda, thanks for input, but I want to check some other variable as mentioned item.result first and if that returns true call a function and display hw_interface. The above suggested answer won't check for item.result

Comment: In the function can check any items with any parameter and return false or true, or in **ng-if** can check with `ng-if="item.result === 1 && ctrl.hw_interface === true"` or If you need only this one is defined `ng-if="item.result && ctrl.hw_interface"`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting your driverInfo() function inside the span instead? Where the driverInfo function returns the value of whatever you want hw_interface variable to be? So if item.result returns a truthy value, then the driverInfo function will run returning the value of hw-interface in the span.

```html
<td class="rsp-p1">
        <span ng-if="item.result">
          {$ctrl.driverInfo() }</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on DelhiPanda's answer:

```
ctrl.myfunc = function() {
   //do some time consuming work
   return false; //true;
};

<td class="rsp-p1">
   <span ng-if="item.result && ctrl.myfunct()">
      {{ ctrl.hw_interface $ }}
   </span>
</td>
```

Reasoning: in checking conditional statements, if both arguments need to be truthy, the second argument will not be valued if the first argument is false. In other words, the function will not be run.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Put driverInfo() function inside the div with condition block it will work.

```html
<div ng-if="item.result">

   {$ctrl.driverInfo() }

</div>
```